# How to return response immediately for requests going over HAProxy rate-limit sessions

Tags: haproxy

How do I immediately return a specific HTTP response for requests going over rate-limit sessions instead of requests block and go into backlog?

I have this current setup:

```
frontend badtest
  bind 127.0.0.1:8811
  acl is_bad path_reg -i ^\/services\/1.0\/test\/.+\/bad
  use_backend throttle_bad if is_bad
  default_backend servers_bend

backend throttle_bad
  server throttleBAD 127.0.0.1:8812

frontend throttle_bad_backend
  bind 127.0.0.1:8812
  rate-limit sessions 45
  acl too_fast fe_sess_rate ge 45
  use_backend er_toofast if too_fast
  default_backend servers_bend

backend er_toofast
  errorfile 503 /var/lib/haproxy/503.http
```

With the above setup, I see status FULL for *throttle_bad_backend* when there are too many requests.

And what doe status = FULL mean?

Comment: It sounds like you need a larger `maxconn` and/or smaller `maxqueue` on the `throttlebad` backend.  You're looping out and back in to HAProxy with this config so the number of concurrent connections is being constrained *before* the rate limit test.